# Can anyone provide my the sample cover letter or can assist my what and how to write cover letter?

Tags: uk

My UK visit visa got refused and nw I want to apply again immediately. I had applied for UK visit visa but it got refused due to some reasons as mentioned in refusal letter. The mistake I did is that I forgot to submit my salary account statement but apart from this.they raised some more concern regarding my trip. Please see the attached refusal letter and advice me. I had submitted the imvitation letter from my brother in law with all required docs(his account statement, invitation, letter, passport copy,telephone bill). My suggest me what all things i should consider for reapplying and content for cover letter. This was my first visa and have no visa history. They refused my visa  under paragraph V4.2(a), (c) and (e) of Appendix V of the immigration letter. Should I apply it again immediately or not? Thnaks[image: ![Refusal letter copy[![][1][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZdi9.jpg)

Comment: From what I read it's unlikely you're going anywhere near the UK soon. Forget it and build up your travel credentials.

Answer (score 0):

A cover letter likely won’t help - you should only reapply immediately if you can fully address all the refusal points. You need to provide evidence of the source of the money in the account you hold with your mother, and demonstrate where your salary goes to eg relevant bank statements. If you can’t do this now, you’d probably be better to wait at least 6-9 months before reapplying, in the meantime start paying in your salary regularly so the ECO can tie up your stated income with the supporting documents.